# How to get offline message of group chat from Openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, groupchat

Is any way in `xmpp` that i get **offline message** of MultiUserChat, when my user login and join room.

I want implement **group chat** like `WhatsApp`, Is any other way to implement this please suggest

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least in `ejjaberd` when you enter the chat group, you have to enter your last timestamp, given that timestamp you will receive the messages from that moment.

Save the timestamp from your last message, and when you enter to your room, like the following:

```
 MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(mConnection, room_name);
                Log.d(TAG, "JOINING => " + room_name);

                DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
                if (mLastMessageDate == null)
                    history.setMaxStanzas(300);
                else
                    history.setSince(mLastMessageDate); //timestamp from your last message

 muc.join(mNickName, null, history,
                            SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for reply, it give me all group chat history.

Comment: If that was the solution, please mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: hi lokesh how to get the time stamp of last message pls help me i am not able to get offline message in group chat

Comment: hi zozelfelfo how can i get timestamp of my last message pls help

Comment: @saurabhdxit If you receive a delayed message, you will be able to extract the timestamp of the message, if not you should just take your current system timestamp. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138627/how-to-get-timestamp-of-incoming-xmpp-message

Comment: How to get chat history of one to one chat?

Comment: @zozelfelfo Solution giving all the message of group since group created .. any idea how to get those message only since the time user left the room ?

Answer (score 0):

First declare a MultiUserChat this way

> private static MultiUserChat muc = null;

then in your oncreate method instantiate it this way

```
muc = new MultiUserChat(CONNECTION, room);
        try {
            muc.join(USERJID);
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and call this method in the beginning of your app

```
void setMessageListner() {
        muc.addMessageListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                Message msg = (Message)packet;
                msg.setSubject(msg,getBody);
                Logger.i("Received message  : "+msg.getBody()+" From "+msg.getSubject());
        });
    }
```

this way whenever the user get into a GroupChat he will get the last Messages of the group

Comment: thanks for reply, i try this but it give me all message of group chat